# Use underscore builtin in script

Tags: python

In an interactive console (in Python) I can do this;

```
k = 5
def generateur(i):
    i += 1
    yield i

for j in generateur(k):
    j

print _
```

Where the `_` variable take latest value. This could be very useful for me, when I loop through a generator and would like raise an exception and print the wrong statement by example. However, `_` doesn't seem to be available when you run a script - e. g. `$ python my_script.py`. (I have tried to use `__builtin__._` but it fails.)

Is there a way to access `_` when running a script?  If not, what alternatives are there that I could take advantage of?

Answer (score 1):

In a script, you can simply write:

```
for j in generateur(k):
    j

print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

`_` is a special variable that only exists in interactive sessions. However, because of Python's scoping rules, the variable `j` continues to exist when the `for` loop terminates. Therefore, you can simply do:

```
for j in generateur(k): 
    pass

print j
```

Comment: mine problem is little more complex than this. Now i know i can't use _. So maybe a more detailed problem in another thread will be better. Mine problem is with sqlite3 and method executemany, if you  put a generator and one of statement in this generator is wrong you can not see the wrong statement.

Comment: Doesn't `executemany()` throw an exception if one of the statements is wrong? If so, you should be able to see the statement that it tried to execute in the traceback.

Comment: From the Python DBAPI documentation, it appears that `sqlite3` should raise a `ProgrammingError` if the SQL is invalid. Does this not occur in your case?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value, then put it somewhere. Explicit is better than implicit.